# SeekBar doesn't catch click event for last value

Tags: android, android-widget

I have SeekBar with range 1 to 4 ( 1 is first and 4 is last val ). When user click on 2 or 3 SeekBar changes value immediately, but user cannot click on 4, needs to drag to 4. How to achieve that when user click at the end of SeekBar, SeekBar change value to 4 ( last ) ? It looks like SeekBar doesn't catch click event for last value, or space where need to click is to small. Is there any way to change this ?

Comment: What Android version are you using? A normal seekbar with SeekBar#setMax(4) called works just fine in ICS.

Answer (score 2):

just add a little padding at the right side like this:

```
SeekBar sk = new SeekBar(this);
sk.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);
```

:)